# Is there any way to use DIgitalOcean VPS as FTP server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ftp

Problem- I need to implement old CCTV footage into the cloud(for image processing), but DVR doesn't support direct cloud upload. it only supports FTP for file uploading if there any way I can achieve this?

```
CCTV ->  DVR(FTP)-> SEVER -> GOOGLE CLOUD
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need to install FTP server software on the VPS. Then you need to set up something that links the FTP server directories to Google Cloud.

Comment: Try this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63964361) for more information